# PowerApps : Implementing Role Based Security In Your PowerApps App

Tags: powerapps

I have created an app using Power Apps. Assume Home Screen has two buttons "admin" and "user". If a user with Admin roles accesses the app he/she should only be able to see "Admin" button. In case user with "User" role logs in, he/she should only be able to see "user" button. Assume users to be a part of Azure Active Directory.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried connecting to Azure AD or the O365 Graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controlling access to app elements based on user security role, there are three approaches to this:

Method 1:
We can make use of Azure Active Directory Groups.
We need to create a custom connector in PowerApps, that would return groups (denotes security role) that the user is a part of.
These groups should be created in Azure Active Director.
The user must belong to a group.

Method 2:
This is more applicable if data source for the app uses security role-based model.
In this case PowerApps will inherit user’s security roles within data source.

Method 3:
Let’s assume to have SQL server database as the data source for our app.
we can create our own security model for e.g. have a user table with columns storing Boolean type values (Bit in SQL Server), each column representing a security role. A value true denotes the user has the corresponding roles assigned.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this several ways depending on how your environment is setup.

1. Keep admin email addresses in a list somewhere (Azure
   SQL/Sharepoint/etc)
2. Connect to the Office365Users Data Source (`View/Data Sources`)
3. Compare User().Email to the list of admins
4. Set the Visibility of the Admin Button to "true" if true, else "false"

Another option is to connect to the Azure AD Data Source and use AzureAD.GetMemberGroups or other like functions to see if the user is part of the correct Security Group.

If you're a small outfit and the admin team will ALWAYS be the admins, you could hardcode it into your app with:

```
If(
    User().Email = bob@mycompany.com,
    true,
    false
)
```